# Passing by a semi truck on a highway

Tags: automotive-engineering, airflow, car

So I’m driving down the highway in my sedan on a speed of lets say 60 mph. Why is it that my car sways just before it passes or it passes me? Almost always where the semis first tire is (closest to the hood)? What forces are acting upon it? What could be a possible explanation to why it happens? Why is it only at that spot that the car sways?

Comment: the truck can also shield you from the natural cross wind...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A truck speeding down a highway creates an envelope stream of high pressure air surrounding it.

This is basically a wake, composed of layers of high pressure shockwaves, created when the front of the truck, hood and cabin penetrate the still air and push it open.

This shockwave moves with the truck and after turning into a small turbulent tail at the backside dissipate slowly.

When you drive near a truck in passing, or it passes by you, your car cuts into the boundary of this wake.

Depending on your car's aerodynamics and your driving habits, the impact of incursion may become more pronounced at a certain point and angle. Some times this impact may be strong enough to steer the car closer to the truck. Or you my lose control by trying to avoid the collision.

I keep away from the big trucks as much as I can, or else try to anticipate the shock and be prepared.

Comment: A Wake is an excellent visual metaphor.  If we could see the air wake, it would be like a speed-boat's wake on the surface of the water, but more three-dimensionally.   A "bullet into ballistics gel" might be another visualisation.

Comment: Technically, a shock wave is not the correct term here. it takes a transonic or sonic speed to create shock waves. However, The pattern you see around boats (in water) are real shock waves. Those two are different flow regimes. On the roads the flow is quite subsonic. Take a look at this lecture notes for a visual introduction to Mach waves. https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-01-unified-engineering-i-ii-iii-iv-fall-2005-spring-2006/fluid-mechanics/f17_sp.pdf

Comment: @GürkanÇetin, right, but here I use the term shockwave in a broad sense as follows. When an obstacle is restricting free flow of a stream of air such as happens in front of a truck, or the tiny blade of a flute , at a rate that can not be discharge in a smooth stream, the pressure will build up and the release will happen in a sudden shock wave leaving the obstacle with a relative vacuum which will immediately fill up and release again causing vibration forming an undulating pressure wave , either following the truck path or getting out from the end of the flute..

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand a semi track travelling on highway has at least three different zones of interest. They are:

1. Front
2. Middle
3. Back

Below are the three regions pictorially.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

In order for the truck to pass through it diverts outwards air in front of the semi truck. The empty area  middle (between the tractor and rear wheels) it creates vacuum which is reason sometime small car like the sedan get dragged toward the semi. The back of the semi also creates air void thus and air gets pulled in thus a small sedan could swayed into the lane the semi is travelling.

Comment: No, there is no "vacuum" behind a truck, not is not even a low-pressure area. It is an area of turbulence and chaos.

Comment: @MichaelK, I didn't state that there is vacuum behind a track. As the picture indicate their is unbalance in air behind the truck.

Comment: *" it creates **vacuum** which is reason sometime small car "*

Comment: @MichaelK that is in the middle, not in the back.

Comment: Same thing, there is no vacuum in the middle either.

Comment: @MichaelK, it is Bernoulli's principle that comes into play. The reduction in air pressure causes to drag into the truck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87673/discussion-between-michaelk-and-mahendra-gunawardena).

Comment: @MichaelK Look up D’Alemberts Paradox and, with needles providing the smoke stream we demonstrated this with a flat plate... which is why yhe back end of many cars gets very dirty due to the lower pressure region that is created.

Comment: @MichaelK, you might want take a look at Kamran comments,  *sudden shock wave leaving the obstacle with a relative vacuum*